# Sample from Vector/Array with Probabilities

Tags: julia

I have a `Bool` vector, simply `[true, false]`. I can draw 10 samples from that vector with

```
rand([true,false], 10)
```

but how can I achieve that `true` is drawn with a 80%-probability and `false` is drawn with a 20%-probability?

Comment: Why did this get a down-vote?? I there is something wrong about the question, please let me know and I can fix it.

Comment: I am not sure - I think it is a valid question.

Comment: Btw. if you sample from `Bool`, you can also use the syntax `rand(Bool, 10)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `sample` function from StatsBase.jl with `Weights` argument:

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> sample([true, false], Weights([0.8, 0.2]), 10)
10-element Array{Bool,1}:
 1
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

And to make sure you get what you wanted you can write:

```
julia> countmap(sample([true, false], Weights([0.8, 0.2]), 10^8))
Dict{Bool,Int64} with 2 entries:
  false => 20003766
  true  => 79996234
```

(of course your exact numbers will differ)

Also if you specifically need binary sampling you can use `Bernoulli` distribution from Distributions.jl:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> rand(Bernoulli(0.8), 10)
10-element Array{Bool,1}:
 0
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1

julia> countmap(rand(Bernoulli(0.8), 10^8))
Dict{Bool,Int64} with 2 entries:
  false => 20005900
  true  => 79994100
```

(you can expect this method to be faster)

Finally - if you do not want to use any packages and need a binary result you can just write `rand(10) .< 0.8`, and again - you get what you wanted:

```
julia> countmap(rand(10^8) .< 0.8)
Dict{Bool,Int64} with 2 entries:
  false => 20003950
  true  => 79996050
```